# Seaborn pointplot aesthetics

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to adjust the size of both the points and the lines in a [seaborn pointplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html).

In other plot types (e.g. [lmplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html?highlight=lmplot)), we can do that through the options `scatter_kws=None, line_kws=None`; however it doesn't look like pointplot has those.

Passing those options anyway, doesn't seem to work; e.g.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(long_df, col=options.group, sharey=options.sharey, sharex=options.sharex, margin_titles=True, col_order = order)
g = g.map(sns.pointplot,options.time,'Abundance','OTU', palette='deep', scatter_kws={'alpha':0.3}).
```

Furthermore, is there any way to adjust the aesthetics of the error bars separately?

Comment: Use the `scale` parameter.

Comment: @mwaskom using the scale parameter would not solve the issues of marker  edgecolor, alpha, etc. - Is there no alternative solution?